# How to get intranet uptime (availability reports) from datadog or newrelic?

Tags: monitoring, newrelic, uptime-monitoring, datadog

We are using DataDog and NewRelic to monitor the performance of few DevOps supported systems and we need to provide some uptime reports like:

- 99.5% up last month (x minutes downtime)
- 99.1% up last year (x minutes downtime)

While we do have URL monitoring configured on DataDog we were not able to find a way to compute the uptime (only to get an alert when the service is down).

NewRelic is also used but it seems that they have an URL monitoring service which works only on publicly accessible sites, making it useless for 9/10 cases.

Comment: If you report the service down/up times using the New Relic Insights API you may be able to build the report using it.

Comment: I think that with either service you could pull up/downtime statistics and build the report with it, as already mentioned. As far as I know, there is no built in service with datadog or newrelic that will do this for you. Datadog does have a pingdom integration, but as you said, it will only monitor servers that can be accessed from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

The Monitor section of Datadog now includes a "Monitor status" page for each of the monitor you define (for example the URL monitoring you already have). On this page, you can see by group/scope the monitor history and it shows you the uptime for that monitor.

More to read about this new feature [here](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-alert-status/)

It's not yet available as a "report" but that's a good idea!